# Python: how do I match values in the dataframe from an input containing single quotes (apostrophe)?

Tags: python, pandas, input, apostrophe, single-quotes

I am coding a Python function that takes an input and displays all the matching values from the dataframe but I don't get any results from an input containing a single quote (apostrophe) '
The dataframe contains values like: Mo'Nique, Thaddeus O'Sullivan, Nancy O'Dell which I can't match by typing the corresponding name.

I have tried to escape the single quote with `.replace("'", "\'")` but didn't work.

Thanks for your help.

NOTE: I am parsing the values twice. First time I search for a match, if none found, I normalize the value and search again before printing name not found.

```
import pandas as pd

def get_name():
    request_name = input("Type a name: ")
    request_name = request_name.lower().title().strip()
    search = False
    for value in df['NameColumn']:
        if request_film in value:
            search = True

    if not search:
        df['NameColumn'] = (
            df['NameColumn'].str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode(
                'ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8'))
        for value in df['NameColumn']:
            if request_name in value:
                search = True

    if search:
        name_data = df.loc[(df['NameColumn'].str.contains(request_name))]
        print(name_data)

    else:
        print("name not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

the single quotes in your df are possibly non-ASCII characters. If it's the case then you can use the `Unidecode` package to convert Unicode characters to their ASCII equivalent. You can try this :

```
from unidecode import unidecode

request_name = 'O\'Dell'

for value in df['NameColumn']:
    value = unidecode(value)
    if request_name in value :
        print(True)
    else :
        print(False)
```

Then you get :

```
False
True
False
```

Comment: No, I'm sorry but it's not working for my case. I'll edit my question to be more specific. I am sure all characters are ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've found the problem which was in the `.title()` method.

The `.title()` method treats the word containing the apostrophe as separate words, so:

```
request_name = input('Type a name: ') #america's
request_name = request_name.lower().title().strip()
print(request_name) #America'S
```

`America'S` of course doesn't match `America's` which is in my `dataframe`.

### Solution 1 (using `.lower()`):

I apply the `.lower()` method to both (copy of my `dataframe` and my input). In this way I can exactly compare the two.

### Solution 2 (using `regex`):

[This solution](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-string-methods/python-titlecase/#:%7E:text=The%20title()%20method%20converts,the%20remaining%20characters%20in%20lowercase), suggests using a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to bypass the problem.